# jQuery unrecognized expression Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with the ids from input fields. I want now clear every value in the input fields.

This is my function:

```
function cleanEdit() {
    //array mit allen Feld Ids
    arr_fields = ["edt_lfd_nummer","edt_objekt","edt_mandant","edt_objektbereich","edt_massnahme","edt_kreditor","edt_auftragssumme","edt_auftragsdatum","edt_auftragsbezeichnung","edt_auftragsgegenstand","edt_fertigstellungsgrad"];
    arr_fields.forEach(function(element) {
    $('"#'+element+'"').val("");
    });
    return true;
}
```

The error I get is

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#edt_lfd_nummer"

I don't want to do

```
$("#edt_objekt").val("");
$("#edt_mandant").val("");
```

for every field, because the array is much much longer than I post here.

Answer (score 1):

> he error i Get is Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   "#edt_lfd_nummer"

Replace this

```
$('"#'+element+'"').val("");
```

with

```
$("#" + element ).val("");
```

Notice that there was an extra **double quote** `"` surrounding the id